# Subtract two datefields (one of them has a min(date)), and get days as result

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this query. I have a registerdate, and the firstorder date(if there is an order).
Now i want the difference between these 2 dates.

```
SELECT c.id,DATE(c.date_register),MIN(DATE(co.date_order))
FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN customer_order co
    ON co.id_customer = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

But this part gives me an error: `DATEDIFF (DAY,DATE(c.date_register),MIN(DATE(co.date_order)))`

Who knows how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30')
```

You need to use like this in your query

```
DATEDIFF (c.date_register,MIN(co.date_order))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DATEDIFF(DATE(c.date_register),MIN(DATE(co.date_order)))
```